# SSIS: How to delimit columns at specific indexes

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a text file which is formatted as follows:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| Field Name | Starting Column | Field Length | Data Type |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| ID         |               1 |           12 | A         |
| DATE       |              13 |            8 | Date      |
| NAME       |              21 |           80 | A         |
| ADDRESS    |             101 |           12 | A         |
| ...        |             ... |          ... | ...       |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

We can see here that the "Starting Column" is the index at the beginning of the column. Therefore, Starting Column combined with Field Length gives us the maximum size each column should be.

I've been using the `Fixed Width` option and it seems to kinda work but I'm getting these weird black boxes which seem to be shifting everything over.

[image]

Comment: What character do you see when opening the file with a text editor?  What text encoding is the file saved as?  Many Microsoft products do not support UTF-8, which is the standard for almost every common non-Microsoft system.

Comment: Without seeing your raw text file, we really can't help with this.

Comment: Those black boxes are the LF and CR characters at the end of your row. Just move your red line 2 spaces over to allow for those characters and it should fix the problem. Just went through the same thing myself with a massive fixed width source file (hundreds of columns, thousands of characters). I feel your pain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying the suggested solutions and doing [more research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125384/ssis-flat-file-connection-manager-corrupted) I found [this](http://www.inner-join.info/SSIS_Flat_File_Row_Delimiter_Not_Recognized.html) thread which led me to try the `ragged right` option in the flat file connection manager which solved my issue. Those two black characters did turn out to be Line Feed (LF-ASCII Char 10) and Carriage Return (CR-ASCII Char 13) characters as @Jacob H suggested.

**Note:** I did also have to add an additional column to the end which I named `Ignore`. This is because otherwise, it wouldn't let me add the data length information for the final columns.

I hope this helps someone else in the future as `ragged right` isn't very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Those two black characters are the **Line Feed** (LF-ASCII Char 10) and **Carriage Return** (CR-ASCII Char 13) characters which denote the end of each row.

You will notice that each row in your screenshot is shifted 2 points. And subsequent rows are shifted by 2 additional points. Row 2 is shifted 4, Row 3 is shifted 6, etc. Your rows are getting cumulatively shorter by 2 each as SQL is counting these characters towards your total fixed width.

To resolve, move your red end-of-row line two characters over to the left. You will also need to adjust that final column width to match the spec.